# ModelState.IsValid is false always in dotnet6 controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0

My models are created using DB first approach(below command).

```
Scaffold-DbContext “Server=127.0.0.1; database=EmployeePortal; user id = sa; password = <MyStringLocalPassword>;Encrypt=False;” Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer –ContextDir Data -OutputDir Models
```

Here are my models

```
public partial class Employee
{
public int Id { get; set; }

public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

public string JobDescription { get; set; } = null!;

public string Number { get; set; } = null!;

public string Department { get; set; } = null!;

public decimal HourlyPay { get; set; }

public decimal Bonus { get; set; }

public int EmployeeTypeId { get; set; }

public virtual EmployeeType IdNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
}

public partial class EmployeeType
{
public int Id { get; set; }

public string EmployeeType1 { get; set; } = null!;

public virtual Employee? Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Below are the scafolded controller method.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,JobDescription,Number,Department,HourlyPay,Bonus,EmployeeTypeId")] Employee employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        }
    }
```

here for me ModelSatate.IsValid is always false.

I can see the below values when I inspect.

[image]

How can I resolve this?

I got a stack overflow post where the solution is to delete and recreate the database.

Is there any other methods?

Comment: `ModelState` is a collection of `ModelStateEntry` which detail the errors. Check out the details for more information about the binding failures.

Comment: When you are making a request to your web API, and the model state is set to invalid, then you must be getting some response on your Swagger UI or Postman (or whatever interface you are using to make the HTTP request call), what is that response? Share a screenshot of that response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your requirement, a way is you can remove

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

from your project file
(double-click the project name or right-click the project to choose Edit Project File).

Or add`?`  like:

```
public virtual EmployeeType? IdNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
```

Comment: as its a project for testing few things, its ok to set it nullable. Working fine for me. Thanks. May I know what went wrong here? Reason why I am asking is these classes and models I have created using DB first approach and scaffolding. So I was wondering why this is not working. @qing-guo

Comment: @JyothishBhaskaran  Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#build-the-app)